# jQuery animate, doesn't animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the animate() function to change the background position of a button on hover, the problem is that instead of 'animating' it just waits the duration (500) and flicks to the new background position - without a smooth transition.

```
$('.confirm').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '0, -40px'});
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: '0, 0'});
});
```

That's the JS I'm using.  Any ideas why it's not doing a smooth transition? It's acting like a timeout.  I have both jQuery and UI defined.

Thanks!

Comment: run this above `$(this).animate();`, `console.log($(this));` what does `$(this)` return?

Comment: [<input class=​"ignore uibutton large confirm" type=​"submit" value=​"Contact Me!">​]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't natively animate a background position. Animation properties expect a single value, like `opacity:1`, `left:'50px'`, etc.

This plugin should add the functionality you need:
http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't manage to get it to work without a plugin, but the good news is that there is one. You could try http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

edit.... rats... sorry... just saw that was already posted XD

Answer (score -1):

Try taking the section animation out of the callback. 
And calling it asynchronously, but with a .delay(500) before it.

Comment: How exactly was that supposed to help?

Comment: @Drake its always a good practice to support your argument/answer/suggestion with a piece/snippet of code so that its clear to every body else...